# replace any url's within a string of text, to clickable links with php

Tags: php, regex

Say i have a string of text such as

```
$text = "Hello world, be sure to visit http://whatever.com today";
```

how can i (probably using regex) insert the anchor tags for the link (showing the link itself as the link text) ?

Comment: Duplicate: See #1038284 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038284/php-parse-links-emails

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use regexp to do this:

```
$html_links = preg_replace('"\b(https?://\S+)"', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
```

Comment: your answer worked like a charm but if i wanna check also presence of www how would i do it?

Comment: @Sarah unless you want to specifically target all url containing only www, this should catch those. If you need to check for www, then just add www\. like so: `\b(http://www\.\S+)` and that should catch only URL with www.

Comment: If the document contains non-ascii characters (like asian languages), you can replace the "\S+" for: "[0-9a-zA-Z-._~:/?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=]+" if the URLs are only ascii characters (othewise don't change it)

Comment: To include https:// too: - $html_links = preg_replace('"\b(http\S+)"', '<a href="$1">Link</a>', $text);

Answer (score 6):

I write this function.
It replaces all the links in a string. Links can be in the following formats :

- [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
- http://example.com
- https://example.com
- example.fr

The second argument is the target for the link ('_blank', '_top'... can be set to false).
Hope it helps...

```
public static function makeLinks($str, $target='_blank')
{
    if ($target)
    {
        $target = ' target="'.$target.'"';
    }
    else
    {
        $target = '';
    }
    // find and replace link
    $str = preg_replace('@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.~]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@', '<a href="$1" '.$target.'>$1</a>', $str);
    // add "http://" if not set
    $str = preg_replace('/<a\s[^>]*href\s*=\s*"((?!https?:\/\/)[^"]*)"[^>]*>/i', '<a href="http://$1" '.$target.'>', $str);
    return $str;
}
```

Edit: Added tilde to make urls work better https://regexr.com/5m16v