# How to replace URL with anchor tag contain dynamic text using PHP?

Tags: php, string, url, text, preg-replace

how do i parse or convert the link to proper `<a>` link format with PHP?

```
"http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-inbound-webhook.html"
```

Here what postmark JSON API `StrippedTextReply` response:

```
"This is example body with link <http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-process-parse.html>"

Possible format:
This is example body with (any link) <http://>
This is example body with <http://> (any link)
```

Expecting result:

```
'This is example body with <a href="http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-process-parse.html">link</a>'
```

Note that text of anchor in dynamic that is before URL in string.

Comment: Use a regular expression to search for `<http:.*?>` and replace it with the link.

Comment: What is meaning of `(any text) <http://> or <http://> (any text)`? Which one?  At least add example of it.

Comment: Just updated my question. hope that clear now

Comment: Related page: [replace any url's within a string of text, to clickable links with php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1798912/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex in [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace URL with anchor. The regex select URL and replace it with anchor tag contain that URL in `href` attribute.

```
preg_replace("/([\w]+)[\s]+<([^>]+)>/", "<a href='$2'>$1</a>", $str);
```

---

**Edit:**
If position of text of anchor in string is unknown (before or after of URL), you need to use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to check value of matched group.

```
preg_replace_callback("/([\w]+)[\s]+<([^>]+)>([\w\s]+)?/", function($matches){
if (isset($matches[3]))
    return "{$matches[1]} <a href='{$matches[2]}'>{$matches[3]}</a>";
else 
    return "<a href='{$matches[2]}'>{$matches[1]}</a>"; 
}, $str);
```

Comment: the text "link" could be any text. as you can see the response format is `(any text) <http://>` so the text is not wrapped inside the anchor

Comment: its not perfect, but it does the job, the response from Postmark API return different link format `(any text) <http://>` or `<http://> (any text)`. and i ll ask Postmark support. thank you tho :)

Comment: you can check here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/367cc95515c2b7f373c02979e581403871ae8e97. `preg_replace_callback()` returns empty

Comment: @tonoslfx Because you make it as comment. Also that string contain multiple URL that in question doesn't mentioned. However see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/535af5c7de70fa1791ad01cbfa69e3aef03fc87e