# Find all links in a string and transform them into anchor tags using PHP

Tags: php, regex

```
http://stackoverflow.com
```

should become

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a>
```

EDIT: It would be great if anchor tags from the original string stayed intact.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798912/replace-any-urls-within-a-string-of-text-to-clickable-links-with-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038284/php-parse-links-emails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Gruber just posted an interesting regex example to capture URLs:
[Daring Fireball regex to get URLs](http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls)

To cut to the chase, the (liberal, long) pattern he chose was:

```
\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))
```

That posits to capture all of the following:

```
http://foo.com/blah_blah
http://foo.com/blah_blah/
(Something like http://foo.com/blah_blah)
http://foo.com/blah_blah_(wikipedia)
(Something like http://foo.com/blah_blah_(wikipedia))
http://foo.com/blah_blah.
http://foo.com/blah_blah/.
<http://foo.com/blah_blah>
<http://foo.com/blah_blah/>
http://foo.com/blah_blah,
http://www.example.com/wpstyle/?p=364.
http://✪df.ws/123
rdar://1234
rdar:/1234
http://userid:password@example.com:8080
http://userid@example.com
http://userid@example.com:8080
http://userid:password@example.com
http://example.com:8080 x-yojimbo-item://6303E4C1-xxxx-45A6-AB9D-3A908F59AE0E
message://%3c330e7f8409726r6a4ba78dkf1fd71420c1bf6ff@mail.gmail.com%3e
http://➡.ws/䨹
www.➡.ws/䨹
<tag>http://example.com</tag>
Just a www.example.com link.
```

So you'd use that pattern with something like [preg_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php), and then iterate over the returned array of matches somehow. I guess. I hate regex.