# PHP make links using preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [replace any url's within a string of text, to clickable links with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798912/replace-any-urls-within-a-string-of-text-to-clickable-links-with-php)

Just a quick question, When I post links like http://www.buddyweb.me it will just appear like that but, but t's not automaticly linked. So how can I **replace** the http://www.buddyweb.me with `<a href = "http://www.buddyweb.me">Google</a>`

Any suggestions are apreciated, thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798912/replace-any-urls-within-a-string-of-text-to-clickable-links-with-php

Comment: Please clarify whether what you want is to process a page and turn urls into links or just echo a link from php?

Comment: The question linked by @Rijk, links to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038284/php-parse-links-emails

Answer (score 1):

Jut like [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#85722)

```
function clickable($url){
    $url                                    =    str_replace("\\r","\r",$url);
    $url                                    =    str_replace("\\n","\n<BR>",$url);
    $url                                    =    str_replace("\\n\\r","\n\r",$url);

    $in=array(
    '`((?:https?|ftp)://\S+[[:alnum:]]/?)`si',
    '`((?<!//)(www\.\S+[[:alnum:]]/?))`si'
    );
    $out=array(
    '<a href="$1"  rel=nofollow>$1</a> ',
    '<a href="http://$1" rel=\'nofollow\'>$1</a>'
    );
    return preg_replace($in,$out,$url);
}
```

Comment: Seems like overkill for what he wants, maybe I don't understand what he wants though.

Comment: He tagged it with php and preg-replace. I thought he wants to replace urls with links in some posted data.

Answer (score 1):

```
$replaced = preg_replace('/(http[s]?:\/\/[^\s]*)/i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for preg-replace, just concatenate varibles around your link.

```
<?

$yourlink = "http://www.buddyweb.me";
$yourDescriptor = "Google";

$linkedlink = "<a href=\"".$yourlink.">$yourDescriptor</a>";

echo $linkedlink;

?>
```

Comment: I think what he wants is to process an entire page and linkify urls.. the SO question linked from the comments has the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])(([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)(/[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)?)#is", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" title=\"\\2\" rel=\"nofollow\">\\2</a>", $string);
```

I would consider this a complicated Regular Expression. However, if you're interested in learning more, I really liked getting started with this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRR9fOXkfRE

Answer (score 0):

Call something that will return it how you like.

```
<?php
$link = "http://stackoverflow.com";
$name = "Stack Overflow";

echo href($link, $name);

function href($link, $name){
$link = "<a href=\"".$link.">$name</a>";
return $link;
}
?>
```